# Problem when passing a singleton to another viewmodel using self.VM.Navigate

Tags: mdriven

In the public part of my app the user starts with a link to a VM (IndexBookingPage) with DVM params. An action looks up the publicbookingpage object from Id, and if found navigate to Eventlist. This part works. But in the Eventlist self is null. Why?
[IndexBookingPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHDlF.png)

[EventList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lvkuu.png)

Answer (score 1):

Don't set self inside a viewmodel.

Instead, use OneSession.oclSingleton by itself. Use a let statement if you think it's too bulky in text to repeat OneSession.oclSingleton.

Why do you have "Requires root" on the IndexBookingPage at all?

Answer (score 0):

I have change to OneSession.oclSingleton instead, and now it works. Is there a rule when to use self or Class.oclSingleton?

I just tried different solutions, thats why I checked required root.